# Android: Infinite Sub-Activity. Will it be a memory issue?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 Activities - A and B

In Activity A containing a list view spawns a new Sub-Activity B. In Acitivty B there is a button that launches Activity A so as to select another Sub-Activity B.

This seem to create an infinite loop scenario where

A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->..............

So if i quit the program halfway, and the go back again will i get an issue?

because my programs has a exception thrown randomly that i have no solution to.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the stack trace we really can't help you. This sounds like it's a really bad design patter though. You should take a look at the different launch modes

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lmodes

Comment: thanks. i resolve this issue. not really sure why. the most likely thing is that i change alot of static variables to non-static to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of exception does your program throw?

And no - this shouldn't be an issue as Android removes unused Activities from memory. The issue would happen if you would hold unused Activities in some variable fields and Android couldn't dispose them.

Comment: no i didn't do this. i suppose i am continuing debugging but the problem is so random and happens in different activity that its difficult to catch.